# Class as parameter on static method - Java

Tags: java, android, jackson

I want to create static method and using jackson on that method to convert json to some object. what i dont understand how to use class as parameter on my static method.

here my code :

```
  static  Object  stringToObject(String jsonString, Class someClass) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    SomeClass Object =  mapper.readValue(jsonString, someClass.class);
    //handling some exception


    return Object;
}
```

that code would error... can someone give me advice how to accomplish that thanks

Comment: Are you trying to create a different object depending on the class you pass as a parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you always want to keep type-safety then the best solution is to use a [generic method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) which is a method with a type variable.

In your situation [`ObjectMapper::readValue`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readValue(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class)) is already a generic method so what you need is to use the correct syntax for your declaration:

```
static <T> T stringToObject(String jsonString, Class<T> clazz) {
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  return mapper.readValue(jsonString, clazz);
}

static void test() {
   Foo foo = stringToObject("...", Foo.class);
}
```

In this way Java [type inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) can make its work and you don't have to specify anything.